# Disable mouse from being able to access VM in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I am writing Kantu tests (that utilize controlling the mouse pointer) that will run on a Windows server and want to set up a similar environment in a VM ahead of time to verify it will work.  I need to find a way to emulate a Windows machine that doesn't have a mouse plugged in since our server won't have a mouse.  To do this I want to disable the mouse in Virtual Box.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do this since I don't see a "disable mouse input" option in the settings.  Can someone tell me how it would be possible to disable any mouse inputs into a Windows VM from a Windows host?

Comment: I'm not sure of a VirtualBox way to do this, but you can probably emulate this inside the Windows guest. Go to *Mouse Properties*, click the *Hardware* tab, select a device and click Properties. In the device properties, (click Change Settings, if necessary, in the *General* tab,) click the *Driver* tab and select *Disable Device*. Repeat for all other mouse devices.